# How to get object size in memory?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, memory, profiling

I need to know how much bytes my object consumes in memory (in C#). for example how much my `Hashtable`, or `SortedList`, or `List<String>`.

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207592/getting-the-size-of-a-field-in-bytes-with-c

Comment: Any container is a relatively small object that holds a reference to some data storage (usually an array) outside the actual container object - and that in turn holds references to the actual objects you added to the container. So the question how much memory a List takes is not even well defined - the size of the list object itself, memory allocated by the list object, total size for everything in the list and the amount of memory that will be freed when the list is collected are all different values.

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/555929/c-memory-usage-of-an-object/556061#556061

Comment: See the benchmarks in the test app I have created: https://github.com/scholtz/TestDotNetCollectionsMemoryAllocation

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio, you can use the new .NET Object Allocation Tool: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/net-object-allocation-tool-performance/

Answer (score 180):

this may not be accurate but its close enough for me

```
long size = 0;
object o = new object();
using (Stream s = new MemoryStream()) {
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.Serialize(s, o);
    size = s.Length;
}
```

Comment: This will put so much more. It adds the DLL name and version, ... **this is not a way to calculate object size.**

Comment: I agree that this is _NOT_ a good way to calculate object size. Serialization may be a rough estimate of entropy, but provides no useful information about memory consumption. This is a complex question without an easy solution.

Comment: I tried your method with List<int> before and after populating with items and it didn't seem to work returning same value - 41. Would you know the reson for it?

Comment: Well I can't see your code but it works fine with List<T>...

static void Main(string[] args)
{
 var a = new List<int>();
 var b = new List<int>();
 var c = new List<int>();

 for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
  b.Add(i);
 for (int i=0; i<200; i++)
  c.Add(i);

 Console.WriteLine(GetSize(a)); // 205
 Console.WriteLine(GetSize(b)); // 717
 Console.WriteLine(GetSize(c)); // 1229
 Console.ReadKey();
}
static long GetSize(object o) {
 long size = 0;
 using (Stream s = new MemoryStream()) {
  var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
  formatter.Serialize(s, o);
  size = s.Length;
 }
 return size;
}

Comment: I have the same problem: the length of a list is 41. The entire content of the stream is "\0\0\0\0����\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\rSystem.Object\0\0\0\0\v", retrieved with `s.Position=0;   var sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(s);   string str = sr.ReadToEnd();`

Comment: Lists in C# are preallocated to whatever sizes the framework designers decided to go with, and then increased when needed. By default it's probably something like 10 elements. So you won't notice any size difference until you add enough elements to require more memory to be allocated.

Comment: Yeah.. Not so accurate... I also got a 41 when I tried it on a list of objects

Comment: if you get 41, you need to replace the object (object o = new object()) with the actual object you want to meassure ;). this is just a dummy

Comment: A Bitmap 8bpp (1 byte per pixel) with size 1000x1000 should have 1 MB. Using this method, I get 2.094 KB. Why??

Comment: It will probably vary depending the state of your object. I don't use Bitmap much so I don't know what kinds of things you would typical do with it but with a blank 1000x1000 Bitmap in .NET fiddle I get 4169. https://dotnetfiddle.net/9Du1W0

Comment: if you want to know "well arranged" how much objects allocate memory, why don't try Performance Profiler in VS? in settings -> General set .NET object allocation information to true and that is it.
This is very simple and fastest way in my opinion.

Comment: Can anyone comment if it is safe to assume this will only report **larger** than real memory consumption? I'm thinking in debug this could be used for a conservative estimate... for guestimating cache sizes for example

Comment: You can use size = s.Length / (1024 * 1024) to get it into MB

Comment: @MatthieuCharbonnier Are you working in Notepad? LOL. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28193622/how-do-i-quickly-resolve-namespaces-in-visual-studio-2015

Comment: In order for this operation to not take up any additional memory, you can use a null stream. In other words, if you are checking the memory size of a big object, you don't have to waste that much memory again just to figure out it's size. Just serialize it to a null stream (the bytes don't get saved, but the bytes get counted) and get the byte count at the end.

Comment: @KCD What you say makes sense. I'll try to build up some proof on that. Thanks for pointing me in a general direction.

Comment: Note that the object (o) has to be marked as **serializable**

Comment: I tried this method to determine the difference in size of an array of ints and an array of longs. It gave me the same answer as using GC.GetTotalMemory before and after each allocation. So I think it's pretty accurate.

Comment: What if the object creates a memory leak? Serialisation won't show you that. What if the object does a huge amount of string manipulation and saves the results into a static class? Once again this won't be shown up. What if the object has a parallel foreach loop that does some huge process that takes up 3gb of ram which is then garbage collected later? Serialization won't show this up either.

Comment: In memory an object have different size than in a MemoryStream

Comment: Compiler says BinaryFormatter is deprecated now. See https://aka.ms/binaryformatter

Answer (score 139):

I don't think you can get it directly, but there are a few ways to find it indirectly.

One way is to use the [`GC.GetTotalMemory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.gettotalmemory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to measure the amount of memory used before and after creating your object. This won't be perfect, but as long as you control the rest of the application you may get the information you are interested in.

Apart from that you can use a profiler to get the information or you could use the [profiling api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384547.aspx) to get the information in code. But that won't be easy to use I think.

See [Find out how much memory is being used by an object in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60820/find-out-how-much-memory-is-being-used-by-an-object-in-c) for a similar question.

Comment: While the "true" answer may be "it can't be done," the better answer is the one that gives you a possible alternative.

Comment: This worked well for me. In my case I was working with a very complex object that couldn't really be serialized easily, so the top ans was out of the question. I used this method with a for loop to get a rough average at each point. Helped me see the difference between when this entity didn't exist vs then it did. Delta == rough size of the entity.

Comment: Well, sometimes I get a number (which then matches other test runs), sometimes I dont. I just wanted to point that out. (Maybe GC was not finished before running the testapp again?  I dont know... )

Answer (score 51):

Unmanaged object:

- `Marshal.SizeOf(object yourObj);`

Value Types:

- `sizeof(object val)`

Managed object:

- Looks like there is no direct way to get for managed objects, Ref:
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/cbrumme/size-of-a-managed-object

Comment: Link's dead, can you edit your answer?

Comment: It is interesting; I have checked Marshal.SizeOf(<bool variable set to false>) and it gave me 4... why if bools are size of 1?

Comment: I think, there is 1 bit relevant but the framework still using the 4bytes or 8bytes  (depending on ur architecture) .... You can read a detailed explanation here https://www.quora.com/In-C-why-is-the-size-of-the-bool-1-byte-Isnt-just-1-bit-enough

Answer (score 29):

OK, this question has been answered and answer accepted but someone asked me to put my answer so there you go.

First of all, it is not possible to say for sure. It is an internal implementation detail and not documented. However, based on the objects included in the other object. Now, how do we calculate the memory requirement for our cached objects?

I had previously touched this subject in this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/biztalk/BizTalkCaching.aspx):

> Now, how do we calculate the memory requirement for our cached
>   objects? Well, as most of you would know, Int32 and float are four
>   bytes, double and DateTime 8 bytes, char is actually two bytes (not
>   one byte), and so on. String is a bit more complex, 2*(n+1), where n
>   is the length of the string. For objects, it will depend on their
>   members: just sum up the memory requirement of all its members,
>   remembering all object references are simply 4 byte pointers on a 32
>   bit box. Now, this is actually not quite true, we have not taken care
>   of the overhead of each object in the heap. I am not sure if you need
>   to be concerned about this, but I suppose, if you will be using lots
>   of small objects, you would have to take the overhead into
>   consideration. Each heap object costs as much as its primitive types,
>   plus four bytes for object references (on a 32 bit machine, although
>   BizTalk runs 32 bit on 64 bit machines as well), plus 4 bytes for the
>   type object pointer, and I think 4 bytes for the sync block index. Why
>   is this additional overhead important? Well, let’s imagine we have a
>   class with two Int32 members; in this case, the memory requirement is
>   16 bytes and not 8.

Comment: This does not answer the question of the OP, how are we supposed to measure the size of a HashSet vs a List?

Comment: @yoelhalb - it does answer, and fairly precisely. There isnt a one-statement or short answer to the question.

Answer (score 19):

The following code fragment should return the size in bytes of any object passed to it, so long as it can be serialized.
I got this from a colleague at Quixant to resolve a problem of writing to SRAM on a gaming platform. Hope it helps out.
Credit and thanks to Carlo Vittuci.

```
/// <summary>
/// Calculates the lenght in bytes of an object 
/// and returns the size 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="TestObject"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
private int GetObjectSize(object TestObject)
{
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    byte[] Array;
    bf.Serialize(ms, TestObject);
    Array = ms.ToArray();
    return Array.Length;
}
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. I didn't have the object class defined as serializable and it threw a "Not marked as serializable error"

Comment: Hi @Kevin Hirst, i tried with this that parsed my dataset to get the size in bytes. Its return me Out of memory exception. I find out that bytes max size is 2 GB ? Have any idea how to manage it?

Comment: @Worgon, do you really need to know how big is your dataset except investigational purposes? I'd rather think up a level, to eliminate such a necessity. 
If you insist, you might think about meausuring of particular datarow size or use abovementioned `GC.GetTotalMemory` approach.

Comment: @Worgon 2GB is a memory size of .NET environment for your Application. You can't easily mange it - only store big objects in other heap.

Comment: This is a copy of the most voted answer, which has it's problem, but this code has several issues, first the binaryformatter is slow, but then there is a memory stream without using, then a copy of the data to an array.

Answer (score 2):

In debug mode

load SOS

and execute dumpheap command.

Comment: looks like something from windbg, and it could be really useful. Can you elaborate how to do this in Visual Studio?

Comment: Here's how to do it in visual studio: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66929670/56621