# get size of DataTable or ArrayList in memory

Tags: c#, memory

There is some articles about
[How to get object size in memory ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605621/how-to-get-object-size-in-memory)
but they does not explain how to get the size of an object in memory.

when I use:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(arrayListObject)

i get error:

> Type 'System.Collections.ArrayList'
>   cannot be marshaled as an unmanaged
>   structure; no meaningful size or
>   offset can be computed.

I also can not get the amount of all free memory, becouse i want to perform this calculation on web applications with a lot of threads, so a need to know exactly how much memory needs specific object.

Comment: Unless you're still stuck at .NET 1.1, you should not use `ArrayList`. Use `List<object>` if you need a list containing any object.

Comment: Question is not about the way to use objects, For now I'm working with DataTable

Answer (score 2):

You want to find out the size in memory of managed objects in code - according to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/cbrumme/archive/2003/04/15/51326.aspx) blog entry, it is not possible.

You need to use a memory profiler to do this (like the [Ants profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/features.htm)).

Comment: I dont want to use profiler, i need to know the size to fire an alert/event or something

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know this because of possible optimizations: Use a memory profiler.

Comment: no, i don't want to know it for optimization, I want to know when my DataTable grows to much, to fire an event...

Answer (score 0):

And what about serializing the DataTable, and then checking its length?

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.IFormatter formatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
formatter.Serialize(stream, YourDataTable);
long length = stream.Length;
```