# How do I quickly resolve namespaces in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, namespaces, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc

When I type a method for which the namespace has not been imported, I get a red wavy underline (aka squiggly red line) that indicates there is an error. Using Visual Studio 2012, I can right click this red line and quickly select the desired namespace using `Resolve > using System.Text.RegularExpressions` from the right-click context menu. I also have the option to fully qualify my method with the complete namespace.

**Using Visual Studio 2012:**

[image: Visual Studio 2012 resolve namespace options]

In Visual Studio 2015 preview, this option is missing from my right-click context menu. Does anyone know how to enable this **-or-** quickly choose the namespace I want?

Comment: Did you perhaps have any other Visual Studio extensions installed?

Comment: The only add-ons I installed are the VS2012 Color Theme Editor and MVC5.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This menu has been changed and a new feature was added. The original menu item has been replaced by "Quick Actions...", which brings up its own sub-menu where I can find the things I'm looking for such as importing namespaces and refactoring options:

[image: Visual Studio 2015 Quick Actions]

Answer (score 10):

@dotnetstep is absolutely correct.

**For an even faster resolution process:**

1. Place the text cursor on the word that is squiggled in red.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> (period).
3. Hit enter.
4. Enjoy quick namespace resolution :)

Comment: In VS2015, with "Lightbulb" actions, you just need to have the cursor on the same line and the C# editor will show any actions available on that line.

Answer (score 5):

This option very much present over there but it change little bit. You have to do following thing.

[image]

You can see yellow bulb and arrow. Just click on that arrow and you see the option or double click on Regex it will popup yellow bulb on left side of that line. Move cursor on that bulb icon and you see option.

[image]