# How to make a PerformanceCounter on static variables?

Tags: c#, performance

Is it possible to make listener like the `PerformanceCounter` on the cpu or memory but need it for a variable during execution to know each time what is the size of the variable (example dictionary).

Comment: *Size* like number of items in the dictionary or *size* like number of bytes in memory?

Comment: I think there is no direct way to retrieve the actual size of the object, but you can use for example MemoryStream. Serialize the object and push it to mem stream. (But, i am not sure if this is good idea).

Comment: @oleksii  bytes in memory will be better

Comment: @BaranovskiyDmitry the variable which i want to make listener is already on DLL so i can just get the name of this variable i think

Comment: @Omega There is nothing out of the box available for that. You can probably start from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3173599/706456)