# Calculate Length in bytes of an object

Tags: c#, arrays, object

Given an `Array` argument to a function passed in as `object`, how can I calculate its length in bytes?
I can get the number of elements as `int L = (arg as Array).Length;`
I've tried

```
Type t = (arg as Array).GetType().GetElementType();
int overallSize = sizeof(t);
```

This fails with:

> The type or namespace name 't' could not be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605621/how-to-get-object-size-in-memory

Comment: I deleted my answer because i just saw its marked as dupe. you can do `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(t)*arr.Length`

Comment: Thanks M.kazem Akhgary, I believe Joey;s response is flawed - it deals with determining the size of a variable rather than what I am after, namely, determining the size of an array (passed as an object) when the type of its elements is known and the total number of elements is also known.