# How to get the size of the objects in a session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

We have an ASP.NET Webforms application, where currently we are storing our session data in a State Server. Now we wish to increase the session timeout period for the application.

This is Of course possible, but for this we need to calculate the new hardware requirements.

And hence we need to see the size of the objects stored in the session. Could you please suggest any way/tool that can help us to identify the size of various objects stored in the session.

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I tried this but it just gives the overall size of the session and not the size of all the objects contained in it.

Answer (score 2):

NO, in that case you will have calculate the object before storing to session and make a total memory footprint size. See here on how you can get the size of object

[How to get object size in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605621/how-to-get-object-size-in-memory)

Comment: I think may be memory profilers (not sure though) can come in handy, but as a last resort I would definitely try this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> we need to see the size of the objects stored in the session.

In State Server, you cannot see individual Session's size.

However, you can see the over all memory usage of **aspnet_state.exe** inside Task Manager. I believe it is enough to determine how much memory you need for new server.

If you want very detail, you want to spin up a new SQL Server *(just for few hours to few days)* to store session state, and then query the following to get the individual session state object -

```
SELECT [sessionid],[created], datalength(SessionItemLong) 
FROM ASPStateTempSessions
```

### Other Thought

If you are making a total new environment, I would suggest you to look at [StackExchange's Redis Cache](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis) which is also used in Windows Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get the size of all objects stored in the current Session:

```
public long GetSessionSize()
{
    long totalBytes = 0;
    System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter b = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
    MemoryStream m;

    try
    {
        foreach (string key in Session)
        {
            //--- First add size of key
            totalBytes += key.Length * 2;

            //--- Next add size of object if it exists
            Object x = Session[key];
            if (x != null)
            {
                m = new MemoryStream();
                b.Serialize(m, x);
                totalBytes += m.Length;
            }
        }
    }
    catch { }

    return totalBytes;
}
```