# Ways to determine size of complex object in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, memory, memory-management

Are there ways at determining the total size of a complex object in .NET?  This object is composed of other objects and might hold references to other complex objects.  Some of the objects encapsulated by this object might be POD, others may not.

Comment: Are the objects serializable?

Comment: they MIGHT be :)  Sorry for being vague, but I'm  trying to make this question as generic as possible.

Comment: What is "POD" in C#/.NET context? It's a C++ term...

Comment: @Pavel, yes, POD is a C++ term... I'm using POD to refer to int, string, float, double etc... basically the POD types for .NET... value types :)

Comment: I believe the most appropriate CLR term for what you mean is "blittable type" - which is all primitive types (this excludes object references) and structs where all fields are themselves blittable types.

Comment: Wouldn't the C# version of POD be called simple types? By the way, if anyone is like me and have never heard of POD, it stands for *Plain Ol' Data*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you have is not a "complex object", it's an object graph. To determine its total size, you need to walk that graph - starting with some root object, and using Reflection to enumerate fields of reference types and retrieving their values (and checking for loops, of course).

To get the size of a particular object in the graph, see [this answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128315/find-size-of-object-instance-in-bytes-in-c/1128674#1128674), but note that this is an evil hack, completely unsupported, may break (and may already be broken), and may result in a wholesale kitten genocide in heavenly spheres. That said, there is no "non-hacky" way to get a precise value, because it is an implementation detail by definition - you shouldn't have any use for it. And for the purpose of finding out the memory usage of an app during debugging/profiling, the hack is good enough.

Comment: Thanks Pavel.  I understood the complexities when I asked the question, I was just curious as to if someone had already created an object graph traversal which calculated this :)

Answer (score 4):

Put simply, there is no way to know. Assuming all the objects are serializable, you could use a BinaryFormatter to serialize them into a binary blob, and then read the size of that. However, this would include some metadata, and inflate the actual object size (but it would be a reasonable estimate).

For value types, you would use `Marshal.SizeOf()`, only it does not take into account any subobjects. It would calculate any internal reference type as the size of the pointer to it.

Reflection is another way, but would not expose any private members taking up memory. So, unless I'm mistaken, there is no way to really do this properly.

Answer (score 2):

Tricky...

What if two objects point to the same string variable. Which one "owns" the string? It sounds to me you need to simulate a garbage collection to get a true answer. Not exactly light weight.

Comment: @Paul: what does immutability have to do with this? The point is that an object may hold a reference to a string that has been given to it from the outside (e.g. a filename). Does that string "belong" to the object or not? Should it be counted as part of its size or not?

Answer (score 1):

Give `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf()` a shot.

Comment: `Marshal.SizeOf()` cannot take into account the size of subobjects.

Comment: Keep in mind it's a security critical function, so does not work in a lot of contexts unfortunately.

Comment: It gives the size of the marshaled representation of the object, which isn't quite the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Previously answered elsewhere on StackOverflow:

[Find size of object instance in bytes in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1128674/147511)

You need to introduce unsafe code (due to pointer operations required for this) - the code looks like this:

```
static unsafe int CalcSize(object obj)
{
    RuntimeTypeHandle th = obj.GetType().TypeHandle;
    int size = *(*(int**)&th + 1);
    return size;
}
```

Also remember to mark the project settings (Project->Build tab) to "Allow unsafe code".