# General feedback on my settings for Output Caching

Tags: c#, asp.net, outputcache

I use asp.net 4 c# and Output Caching.

I have a simple CMS, the homepage take a while to load 2,47 seconds latency and I found out that I can boost its performance to 0,67 seconds latency using Output Caching.

The homepage contains a list of recent articles and news, these contents are usually updated once a day, and it is not really important they are updates as soon as the new content have been published.

At the moment I use **expiration time for Output Caching to 600 seconds**, but I was thinking to **increase this value to 6000 seconds**.

Content pages are quite static and the **expiration time for Output Caching to 600 seconds**

I'm afraid that a high values of expiration could create a **bottleneck** in my application (let s imagine a scenario where I have to keep in memory cache for many pages for long time).

Could you provide me your opinion on and if is possible your advice on a "general setting" for a similar scenario?

Probably I missed some concept so I0m note able to answer my questions.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Every application had a different architecture and different caching needs. There is no "typical" apart from the defaults.

Comment: Oded you are right, I understand you point, just I would like have an opinion about the "bottleneck" possible problem, and a very general feedback on my settings.

Comment: Without exact knowledge of how much ram you have, the size of a typical cache entry, how many entries you expect (as a function of time), it is impossible to estimate.

Comment: In addition, the logner you cache the less the gain. As in: caching 1 minute means one request every mionute which may be instead of 100 per second.  That is a gain of factor 6000. Caching one hour only means 1/60th of the requests (one per minute). I dont think more than 5 minutes makes sense in most cases.

Comment: THAT SAID: 2.47 is SLOW for a CMS. THe alst I wrote had this (with article list etc.) without caching in less than 0.05 seconds. SOMETHING is bad here-  I suggest adding a profiler and finding the bottleneck.

Comment: I'm  beginner, you gave me good point to think about. How to measure a typical cache entry?

Comment: Thanks TomTom, 0.05 seconds seems a really fast result to me. I'm sure it also depend on hardware and architecture.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128315/find-size-of-object-instance-in-bytes-in-c-sharp