# Ensuring a SProc doesnt return too much data

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0, datatable

im wondering how you would ensure that the results returned from a SProc, and stored in a datatable, are not too large to be handled in memory.

Ive had a dig already and found the following [Find size of object instance in bytes in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128315/find-size-of-object-instance-in-bytes-in-c-sharp) but the selected answer suggests not doing this.

Im assuming this is an issue which has been solved before so id appreciate any pointers.

Thanks.

Comment: Does the sproc return variable-length fields, like `VARCHAR(MAX)`,  `VARBINARY(MAX)` or similar?

Comment: Atm, the database just contains float, and datetime2 datatypes.

Comment: just limit your resultsets with `SELECT TOP 1000` or similar.

Comment: im assuming its possible to have a loop set up in c# to select 1001 to 2000 etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to implement paging.

To do this, add `@pageNum` and `@pageSize` parameters to your `SP` and change the query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY whatever_field) rn
        FROM    (
--              here goes the old query
                ) q
        WHERE   rn BETWEEN @pageSize * @pageNum + 1 AND @pageSize * (@pageNum + 1)
        ) q
ORDER BY
        wnatever_field
```

Comment: i had just stumbled upon the same idea after u suggested returning the results in chunks. I'll experiment with the above and see how i get on. Thanks very much for your help, i really appreciate it.