# How do I find the size of MemoryCache, preferrably programatically?

Tags: c#, memorycache

I want to find the size of a `MemoryCache`.

```
MemoryCache _cache = MemoryCache.Default;
_cache.Add("key", "value");
FindSize(_cache);
```

I want to implement the `FindSize()` method.

Comment: Answer specific to getting the size of the MemoryCache: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35528813/564726

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid you can't find size of .NET object at runtime. See these answers for more details:

- [Getting the size of a field in bytes with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207592/getting-the-size-of-a-field-in-bytes-with-c-sharp#207605)
- [Find size of object instance in bytes in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128315/find-size-of-object-instance-in-bytes-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the `_cache.Count()` value or something different?