# Tracking memory usage in C#

Tags: c#, .net, caching, memory-management

We are maintaining an in-process, in-memory cache of messages, shared across threads. A message is a tree of `JToken` (usually a `JObject` with lots of properties and subproperties).

We want to keep track of the memory usage of this cache, as realistically as possible.

Right now, we calculate the memory cost of a message by calculating the number of bytes it takes once serialized to BSON, but this is likely to be quite far off the actual memory usage of a tree of small objects in the .NET VM.

Is there a better way to track the memory consumption of our cache?

Comment: You'd better not to use `JObject` for caching. I loaded a 500-600 MB file to memory as `JObject`, and it took about 10 GB of memory. Finally, we moved from `JObject` to `dynamic`(ExpandoObject). It consumes 3-5 times less memory than `JObject`. For the same file it took only 2GB of memory.

Comment: @JurySoldatenkov That's an interesting observation. Not sure why using `dynamic` would reduce memory usage though. Any idea? In any case, if we can afford it, we'd like to stick to caching pre-parsed messages, i.e. caching them as trees of `JToken`.

Comment: it's because `JToken` based classes contain multitude of metadata fields. It envelops every detail in a JToken based class. You can [check it yourself](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/tree/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq). In fact,  `dynamic` is [`ExpandoObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx) which is very similar to dictionary internally. It doesn't have redundant envelopes and metadata.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35528813/17034

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the tip! I'll investigate to check if switching to `dynamic` helps in our case, but based on your analysis, it should. It also shows how far from the real memory usage we must be right now...