# How to gain memory consumption for array a with n rows and m columns?

Tags: c#, arrays, function, memory, row

How to get the allocated space in memory for array A with N rows and M columns in C# ?

is there any function or something like this ?

I search several times in internet; but i can't find any good answer for my question that i understand that.

Comment: What do you mean by 'gain memory consumption'?

Comment: _" i can't find any good answer for my question that i understand that."_ I don't understand _your question_.

Comment: You need to be more clear about what you want. Do you want to reclaim memory after freeing an array or what?

Comment: Are you trying to allocate an array or resize an existing array?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128315/find-size-of-object-instance-in-bytes-in-c-sharp

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the size of a field in bytes with C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207592/getting-the-size-of-a-field-in-bytes-with-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know that how much memory a two dimensional array will consume, then it will depend on the data type.

e.g. if you have an array of 3 rows and 4 columns with type `int` then as an `int` consumes 32 bit or 4 bytes. So whole array will consume 32*3*4 = 384 bits or 4*4*3 = 48 bytes.

For simple calculation you can use following code for getting the memory consumption by different value types:

```
var size = BitConverter.GetBytes(value).Length; // here value can be any value type.
```

Answer (score 2):

You [can't know](https://stackoverflow.com/a/207605/1010363) the exact size occupied in memory by the entire array with all mem-paddings and etc. You can use the following approach to estimate of how many bytes in memory occupied by all array cells.:

```
long size1 = GetArrayElementsSizeInMemory(new int[] { 1, 2 }); // 8 bytes
long size2 = GetArrayElementsSizeInMemory(new int[,] { { 1 }, { 2 }, { 3 } }); // 12 bytes
long size3 = GetArrayElementsSizeInMemory(new int[][] { new int[] { 1, 2 }, new int[] { 3, 4 } }); // 16 bytes
//...
static long GetArrayElementsSizeInMemory(Array array) {
    return array.Length * GetArrayElementSize(array);
}
static long GetArrayElementSize(Array array) {
    var elemenType = array.GetType().GetElementType();
    return elemenType.IsValueType ? Marshal.SizeOf(elemenType) : IntPtr.Size;
}
```